# Guild Wars trial key is full of X's and doesn't work

Tags: guild-wars

I got a Guild Wars trial key by clicking [the free trial button on their website](http://www.guildwars.com/freetrial/), however, it's full of X's, and trying to plug it into the game doesn't work. I'm really not sure what to do - I can't seem to obtain the full trial code. I checked my email but didn't see any emails from guild wars.

Any ideas? Am I missing something really obvious?

[This is the client that I downloaded.](http://www.guildwars.com/support/downloadclient/)

[image]

Comment: have you tryed with your login information to there site?

Comment: Wohoo! Also make note that one's username is **NOT** `<username>@ncsoft.com` , it's `<username>@ncsoft` . There's no `.com`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look closely at the nearby text, you can see that the trial code *has already been used* on the account. Most of the code is X'ed out, because it now just serves to let you distinguish between different codes you may have applied at some point.

You don't need to enter the code again, you should be able to simply start up the game and play.

Comment: You'll use your NCSoft username and password to log into the game unless you set up a seperate username/password specifically for Guild Wars.

Answer (score 5):

The serial code has already been applied to your NCSoft account. The reason it is full of X's is because they obfuscate full codes on your account details. Since the key is already applied, you should now be able to log into Guild Wars using the email and password you have chosen for the account.

The email will *likely* be the email associated with the NCSoft account (what you've scribbled out, though this may be different) and your password **may or may not** be the same as your NCSoft Master Account, depending on what you have chosen. You control the passwords for your Master Account and your Guild Wars account separately, so if you cannot log in using your NCSoft Master Account details, it's likely because they are different than your Guild Wars account itself.

Comment: Because you answered first. Both answers were equally valuable.

Comment: @rlb.usa Michael's answer was first :P just hover over the timestamp ("answered 1 hour ago" or similar) to see.  That said, +1 to both answers from me.